# How can I show all databases in MySQL and foreach database show all tables

Tags: php, mysql

I can show all databases and I can show all tables for a specific database but I want to make a loop or a foreach in PHP to get all databases in MySQL and foreach database show all tables linked to database name. I want an array like this...
`Array ( [database_name] = employees, [tables] = name, surame)` just an example

I tried

```
$db = new MysqliDb('');
$All_databases = $db->rawQuery('SHOW DATABASES'); // this gets all databases
foreach ($All_databases as $key => $value) {
    $AllDbs[] = $value['Database']; // array of all databases found

    $dbname = $value['Database'];  // assign $dbname as a database name

    foreach ($AllDbs as $tbl) {    // foreach database found find its tables

        $db2 = new MysqliDb($dbname);
        $db_tables = $db2->rawQuery('SHOW TABLES');

        foreach ($db_tables as $tbl) {
            $table_name = $tbl['Tables_in_'.$dbname.''];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing a space between in `$All_databases` and `as` in `foreach ($All_databases as $key => $value)`

Comment: edited it thanx but stil not giving what i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a lot simpler to use [information_schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html) tables to query such information, specifically SCHEMATA and TABLES tables will be useful for you.

To get what you want in a single query, just left join TABLES on SCHEMATA and use group_concat() to produce the list of tables separated by comma:

```
select s.SCHEMA_NAME, group_concat(t.TABLE_NAME)
from information_schema.SCHEMATA s
left join information_schema.TABLES t on s.SCHEMA_NAME=t.TABLE_SCHEMA
group by s.SCHEMA_NAME
```

Comment: i get the following error ....    Employees.SCHEMATA' doesn't exist...where employees is my first database found

Comment: Sorry, you need to add the information_schema as database to the table names. See updated answer.